# Is it possible to Vectorize functions that output bigz objects?

Tags: r, vectorization, factorial, gmp

I suspect that there must be some way, for example `gmp`'s `factorialZ` seems pre-vectorized:

```
> library(gmp)
> factorialZ(0:9)
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 10:
 [1] 1      1      2      6      24     120    720    5040   40320  362880
```

and it appears to be comfortable being used with base R functions that take a vector input and give vector output

```
> cumsum(factorialZ(0:9))
Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 10:
 [1] 1      2      4      10     34     154    874    5914   46234  409114
```

However, probably because of coercion, attempting to `Vectorize` a function that outputs bigZ objects will be met with horrible failure:

```
leftFactorial<-function(n)
{
  sum(factorialZ(0:(n-1)))
}
> Vectorize(leftFactorial)(1:10)
  [1] 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00
 [36] 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00
 [71] 00 00 01 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 9a 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01
[106] 00 00 00 6a 03 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 1a 17 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
[141] 9a b4 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 1a 3e 06 00
```

So what should we do when we want to `Vectorize` a function that outputs bigZ objects?

Comment: `Vectorize(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` ?

Comment: @rawr Wow, that was a quick and easy solution. It appears to work perfectly. So how does that work? ```sapply```'s docs don't make it obvious why ```Vectorize``` would make the bigz objects break so badly.

Comment: @rawr, post as answer (maybe with explanation)?

Comment: @rawr I second the recommendation to repost that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dput` allows to visualize the internal structure of a `bigZ` object : a vector of `raw`

```
> dput(factorialZ(0:9))
structure(as.raw(c(0x0a, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x78, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
0xd0, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 
0x00, 0xb0, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x9d, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x89, 0x05, 0x00)), class = "bigz")
```

Using `Vectorize` with `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` results in a simplified vector of `raw` objects.

As noted in comments, `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` works because it keeps the original `Big Integer`  type:

```
Vectorize(leftFactorial, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)(1:10)

[[1]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 1

[[2]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 2

[[3]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 4

[[4]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 10

[[5]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 34

[[6]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 154

[[7]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 874

[[8]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 5914

[[9]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 46234

[[10]]
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 409114
```